# NPE at JSON parsing when testing controller with MockMVC

Tags: java, json, spring, junit, mockmvc

I'm writing tests for my controller and I'm getting NPE when performing post with JSON. The same JSON works fine with Postman (only added escape slashes) but jackson (JSON parser I'm using) can't parse it in my test.

Here is **UserControllerTest** :

```
public class UserControllerTest {

private static final String DEFAULT_REGISTER_JSON = "{\"username\":\"example\"," +
        "\"password\":\"example\"," +
        "\"email\":\"newUser@example.com\"}";

private UserServiceBean userServiceBeanMock = mock(UserServiceBean.class);
private ObjectMapper mapperDummy = mock(ObjectMapper.class);

private MockMvc mockMvc;

private UserController sut = new UserController(userServiceBeanMock, mapperDummy);

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(sut).build();
}

@Test
public void shouldRegisterNewUser() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/users").content(DEFAULT_REGISTER_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(content().json("{\"status\":\"User created\"}"));
}
}
```

Here is my controller method to handle that request:
**UserController.createUser**:

```
// CREATE A USER
@PostMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<ObjectNode> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    ObjectNode jsonObject = mapper.createObjectNode();
    userService.saveUser(user);
    jsonObject.put("status", "User created.");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

And here is JSON from Postman that works perfectly fine when my app is running and I'm testing 'by hand':

```
{
"username":"example",
"password":"password",
"email":"newUser@example.com"
}
```

And stack trace after running that test:

```
    22:20:04.469 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:04.474 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:04.474 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
22:20:04.791 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking for request mappings in application context: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@1372ed45
22:20:05.012 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - 2 request handler methods found on class com.doublemc.controllers.UserController: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)={[/users],methods=[POST]}, public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.deleteUser(java.security.Principal)={[/users],methods=[DELETE]}}
22:20:05.021 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/users],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)
22:20:05.033 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/users],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.deleteUser(java.security.Principal)
22:20:05.654 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
22:20:05.657 [main] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
22:20:05.706 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver - Found javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath containing 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 2 environment. Trying to instantiate JPA aware TraversableResolver
22:20:05.708 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver - Instantiated JPA aware TraversableResolver of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
22:20:05.721 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom MessageInterpolator of type org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocaleContextMessageInterpolator
22:20:05.724 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl - Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21
22:20:05.726 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
22:20:05.728 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
22:20:05.729 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
22:20:05.729 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
22:20:05.779 [main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@1372ed45
22:20:05.833 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Looking for exception mappings: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StubWebApplicationContext@1372ed45
22:20:05.864 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Initializing servlet ''
22:20:05.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:05.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:05.880 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:05.880 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
22:20:05.880 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
22:20:05.880 [main] INFO org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
22:20:05.881 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
22:20:05.883 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling provided
22:20:05.884 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using LocaleResolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@4e423aa2]
22:20:05.884 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using ThemeResolver [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@7fbdb894]
22:20:05.888 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using RequestToViewNameTranslator [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@3081f72c]
22:20:05.888 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Using FlashMapManager [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@3148f668]
22:20:05.888 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet '' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.]
22:20:05.888 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 7 ms
22:20:05.888 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Servlet '' configured successfully
22:20:05.928 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [/users]
22:20:05.930 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /users
22:20:05.934 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]
22:20:06.012 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [class com.doublemc.domain.User] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3da30852]
22:20:06.038 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.040 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.041 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.044 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.doublemc.controllers.UserControllerTest.shouldRegisterNewUser(UserControllerTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.doublemc.controllers.UserControllerTest.shouldRegisterNewUser(UserControllerTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    ... 37 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I found that those lines are the most important ones (at least I think so):

```
    22:20:05.928 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name '' processing POST request for [/users]
22:20:05.930 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /users
22:20:05.934 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]
22:20:06.012 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Read [class com.doublemc.domain.User] as "application/json" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@3da30852]
22:20:06.038 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.040 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.041 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode> com.doublemc.controllers.UserController.createUser(com.doublemc.domain.User)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:20:06.044 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```